# How to find the largest element in a list of integers recursively?

Tags: list, scala, max

I'm trying to write a function which will recursively find the largest element in a list of integers. I know how to do this in Java, but can't understand how to do this at Scala.

Here is what I have so far, but without recursion:

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
    else xs.max;
  }
```

How can we find it recursively with Scala semantic.

Comment: Do you consider the fold and reduce methods to be recursive?  They are in a mathematical sense.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is the most minimal recursive implementation of max I've ever been able to think up:

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Option[Int] = xs match {
  case Nil => None
  case List(x: Int) => Some(x)
  case x :: y :: rest => max( (if (x > y) x else y) :: rest )
}
```

It works by comparing the first two elements on the list, discarding the smaller (or the first, if both are equal) and then calling itself on the remaining list.  Eventually, this will reduce the list to one element which must be the largest.

I return an Option to deal with the case of being given an empty list without throwing an exception - which forces the calling code to recognise the possibility and deal with it (up to the caller if *they* want to throw an exception).

If you want it to be more generic, it should be written like this:

```
def max[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: List[A]): Option[A] = xs match {
  case Nil => None
  case x :: Nil => Some(x)
  case x :: y :: rest => max( (if (x > y) x else y) :: rest )
}
```

Which will work with any type which either extends the `Ordered` trait or for which there is an implicit conversion from `A` to `Ordered[A]` in scope.  So by default it works for `Int`, `BigInt`, `Char`, `String` and so on, because scala.Predef defines conversions for them.

We can become yet more generic like this:

```
def max[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: Seq[A]): Option[A] = xs match {
  case s if s.isEmpty || !s.hasDefiniteSize => None
  case s if s.size == 1 => Some(s(0))
  case s if s(0) <= s(1) => max(s drop 1)
  case s => max((s drop 1).updated(0, s(0)))
}
```

Which will work not just with lists but vectors and any other collection which extends the `Seq` trait.  Note that I had to add a check to see if the sequence actually has a definite size - it might be an infinite stream, so we back away if that might be the case.  If you are sure your stream will have a definite size, you can always force it before calling this function - it's going to work through the whole stream anyway.  See notes at the end for why I *really* would not want to return `None` for an indefinite stream, though.  I'm doing it here purely for simplicity.

But this doesn't work for sets and maps. What to do?  The next common supertype is `Iterable`, but that doesn't support `updated` or anything equivalent.  Anything we construct might be very poorly performing for the actual type.  So my clean no-helper-function recursion breaks down.  We *could* change to using a helper function but there are plenty of examples in the other answers and I'm going to stick with a one-simple-function approach.  So at this point, we can to switch to `reduceLeft` (and while we are at it, let's go for `Traversable' and cater for *all* collections):

```
def max[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: Traversable[A]): Option[A] = {
  if (xs.hasDefiniteSize) 
    xs reduceLeftOption({(b, a) => if (a >= b) a else b}) 
  else None
}
```

but if you don't consider reduceLeft recursive, we can do this:

```
def max[A <% Ordered[A]](xs: Traversable[A]): Option[A] = xs match {
  case i if i.isEmpty => None
  case i if i.size == 1 => Some(i.head)
  case i if (i collect { case x if x > i.head => x }).isEmpty => Some(i.head)
  case _ => max(xs collect { case x if x > xs.head => x })
}
```

It uses the `collect` combinator to avoid some clumsy method of bodging a new Iterator out of `xs.head` and `xs drop 2`.

Either of these will work safely with almost any collection of anything which has an order.  Examples:

```
scala>  max(Map(1 -> "two", 3 -> "Nine", 8 -> "carrot"))
res1: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((8,carrot))

scala> max("Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious")
res2: Option[Char] = Some(x)
```

I don't usually give these others as examples, because it requires more expert knowledge of Scala.

Also, do remember that the basic `Traversable` trait provides a `max` method, so this is all just for practice ;)

Note: I hope that all my examples show how careful choice of the sequence of your case expressions can make each individual case expression as simple as possible.

*More Important Note:* Oh, also, while I am intensely comfortable returning `None` for an input of `Nil`, in practice I'd be strongly inclined to throw an exception for `hasDefiniteSize == false`.  Firstly, a finite stream could have a definite or non-definite size dependent purely on the sequence of evaluation and this function would effectively randomly return `Option` in those cases - which could take a long time to track down.  Secondly, I would want people to be able to differentiate between having passed `Nil` and having passed truly risk input (that is, an infinite stream).  I only returned `Option` in these demonstrations to keep the code as simple as possible.

Comment: you can use `x.max(y)` instead of the `if-else`

Comment: @Chirlo no, I cannot and I would not.  Did you notice that my code is as generic as possible?  I *cannot* because the `Ordered` trait does not define any such method.  Hell, `Int` doesn't either, but RichInt does, so an implicit conversion takes care of that.  I *would not*, in any case, because it could cause confusion to the reader (or error by the coder) inside a function which is itself called `max`

Comment: I meant on your first example in which you do use `Int` , guess I should have been clearer.

Comment: No problem.  Yes, I could.  No, I wouldn't. ;)

Answer (score 18):

The easiest approach would be to use max function of `TraversableOnce` trait, as follows,

```
val list = (1 to 10).toList
list.max
```

to guard against the emptiness you can do something like this,

```
if(list.empty) None else Some(list.max)
```

Above will give you an `Option[Int]`

My second approach would be using `foldLeft`

```
(list foldLeft None)((o, i) => o.fold(Some(i))(j => Some(Math.max(i, j))))
```

or if you know a default value to be returned in case of empty list, this will become more simpler.

```
val default = 0
(list foldLeft default)(Math.max)
```

Anyway since your requirement is to do it in recursive manner, I propose following,

```
def recur(list:List[Int], i:Option[Int] = None):Option[Int] = list match {
  case Nil => i
  case x :: xs => recur(xs, i.fold(Some(x))(j => Some(Math.max(j, x))))
}
```

or as default case,

```
val default = 0
def recur(list:List[Int], i:Int = default):Int = list match {
  case Nil => i
  case x :: xs => recur(xs, i.fold(x)(j => Math.max(j, x)))
}
```

Note that, this is `tail recursive`. Therefore stack is also saved.

Comment: Like your first approach. Since it is definetly the easiest one, is there any reason why recursion would be better (beside that the question asked for recursion)?

Comment: Not that I can think of. We used to write the recursion functions for that kind of simple applications when we are learning the scala.

Answer (score 13):

If you want functional approach to this problem then use `reduceLeft`:

```
def max(xs: List[Int]) = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException
  xs.reduceLeft((x, y) => if (x > y) x else y)
}
```

This function specific for list of ints, if you need more general approach then use `Ordering` typeclass:

```
def max[A](xs: List[A])(implicit cmp: Ordering[A]): A = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException
  xs.reduceLeft((x, y) => if (cmp.gteq(x, y)) x else y)
}
```

`reduceLeft` is a higher-order function, which takes a function of type `(A, A) => A`, it this case it takes two ints, compares them and returns the bigger one.

Comment: Use reduceLeftOption and let the caller decide what to do if an empty list was passed.  It might not be a problem for their code.

Comment: @itsbruce i don't think that using `Option` as a result type in such function is a good design.

Comment: Why not?  Option is a very Scala way of doing something; the signature signals to the caller that there may be a problem but it leaves them the choice of how to deal with it.  It also allows creative use of for comprehensions and Monadic solutions.  Throwing an exception forces the caller to wrap your function in a try/call block if they want do do anything elegant.  `Option` is *much* more composable.

Comment: @itsbruce The problem is that it should not signal, `max` is a primitive operation which should not force the developer to use `Option` all over the code. That's the idea of combinators library, if the developer wants to use `Option` if the list is empty then, according to FP way, he should combine a function which checks for list emptiness and wraps the result to None/Some and a primitive function

Comment: If I were extending the collections combinator code, I'd provide max and maxOption because that matches the style there, but this is a standalone function.  You could call it a question of style, but I prefer to default to the functional style; imperative coders will always find ways to make it imperative, without any help.

Comment: @itsbruce and you told it yourself - `I'd provide max and maxOption`, two functions and i guess your `maxOption` would be just a wrapper around `max`

Comment: In any case, I'll keep using `Option` in examples like this because it's a very simple way to make newcomers think about FP style ;)

Answer (score 8):

You could use pattern matching like that

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => throw new NoSuchElementException("The list is empty")
  case x :: Nil => x
  case x :: tail => x.max(max(tail)) //x.max is Integer's class method
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Scala is a functional language whereby one is encourage to think recursively. My solution as below. I recur it base on your given method.

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if(xs.isEmpty == true) 0
    else{
      val maxVal= max(xs.tail)
      if(maxVal >= xs.head) maxVal 
      else                  xs.head     
    }
  }
```

Updated my solution to tail recursive thanks to suggestions.

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {    
    def _max(xs: List[Int], maxNum: Int): Int = {   
      if (xs.isEmpty) maxNum
      else {
        val max = {
          if (maxNum >= xs.head) maxNum
          else xs.head
        }
        _max(xs.tail, max)
      }
    }
    _max(xs.tail, xs.head)
  }
```

Comment: `if (xs.isEmpty == true)` comparing boolean with boolean is useless in `if` you can just write `if (xs.isEmpty)`

Comment: Your solution is not tail recursive, so vulnerable to stack overflow with long lists.  You might find it easier to fix this if you use pattern matching and a case expression rather than chained if expressions.  (It would also be clearer code).

Answer (score 4):

I used just `head()` and `tail()`

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException
    else maxRecursive(xs.tail, xs.head) 
  }
  
  def maxRecursive(xs: List[Int], largest: Int): Int = {
    if (!xs.isEmpty) {
      if (xs.head > largest) maxRecursive(xs.tail, xs.head)
      else maxRecursive(xs.tail, largest)
    } else {
      largest
    }
  }
```

Here is tests for this logic:

```
test("max of a few numbers") {
    assert(max(List(3, 7, 2, 1, 10)) === 10)
    assert(max(List(3, -7, 2, -1, -10)) === 3)
    assert(max(List(-3, -7, -2, -5, -10)) === -2)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Folding can help:

   ```
   if(xs.isEmpty)
     throw new NoSuchElementException
   else
     (Int.MinValue /: xs)((max, value) => math.max(max, value))
   ```
2. List and pattern matching (**updated**, thanks to @x3ro)

   ```
   def max(xs:List[Int], defaultValue: =>Int):Int = {
     @tailrec
     def max0(xs:List[Int], maxSoFar:Int):Int = xs match {
       case Nil => maxSoFar
       case head::tail => max0(tail, math.max(maxSoFar, head))
     }
     if(xs.isEmpty)
       defaultValue
     else
       max0(xs, Int.MinValue)
   }
   ```

(This solution does not create `Option` instance every time. Also it is tail-recursive and will be as fast as an imperative solution.)

Comment: Starting off with `Int.MinValue` might not be a good idea, since your implementation thus return `MinValue` for an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just starting out with scala so I try to give you the simplest answer to your answer, how do it recursively:

```
 def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
   def maxrec(currentMax : Int, l: List[Int]): Int = l match {
     case Nil => currentMax
     case head::tail => maxrec(head.max(currentMax), tail) //get max of head and curretn max
   }
   maxrec(xs.head, xs)
 }
```

This method defines an own inner method (`maxrec`) to take care of the recursiveness. It will fail ( exception) it you give it an empty list ( there's no maximum on an empty List)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code (I am a newbie in functional programming) and I'm assuming whoever lands up under this question will be folks like me. The top answer, while great, is bit too much for newbies to take! So, here is my simple answer. Note that I was asked (as part of a Course) to do this using only head and tail.

```
/**
   * This method returns the largest element in a list of integers. If the
   * list `xs` is empty it throws a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.
   *
   * @param xs A list of natural numbers
   * @return The largest element in `xs`
   * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if `xs` is an empty list
   */
    @throws(classOf[java.util.NoSuchElementException])
    def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = find_max(xs.head, xs.tail)

    def find_max(max: Int, xs: List[Int]): Int = if (xs.isEmpty) max else if (max >= xs.head) find_max(max, xs.tail) else find_max(xs.head, xs.tail)
```

Some tests:

```
test("max of a few numbers") {
    assert(max(List(3, 7, 2)) === 7)
    intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
      max(List())
    }
    assert(max(List(31,2,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,22)) === 31)
    assert(max(List(2,31,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,22)) === 31)
    assert(max(List(2,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,22,31)) === 31)
    assert(max(List(Int.MaxValue,2,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,222,3,-31,1,2,-1,0,24,1,21,22)) === Int.MaxValue)
  }
```

Comment: you said functional programming.. but I see nothing functional in the solution you provided.. I mean its no different than how we do in an imperative language like C++,  C or others. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

list.sortWith(_ > *).head & list.sortWith(* > _).reverse.head for greatest and smallest number

Comment: list.sortWith( _ > _ ).head list.sortWith( _ > _ ).reverse.head

Comment: Hi @tejas, if you would like to edit your answer, you can do so by clicking the `edit` button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to write a recursive max function on a list using isEmpty, head and tail and throw exception for empty list:

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int =
  if (xs.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException("max of empty list")
  else if (xs.tail.isEmpty) xs.head
  else if (xs.head > xs.tail.head) max(xs.head :: xs.tail.tail)
  else max(xs.tail)
```

if you were to use max function on list it is simply (you don't need to write your own recursive function):

```
val maxInt = List(1, 2, 3, 4).max
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def _max(xs: List[Int], maxAcc:Int): Int = {
    if ( xs.isEmpty ) 
      maxAcc 
    else 
      _max( xs.tail, Math.max( maxAcc, xs.head ) ) // tail call recursive
  }

  if ( xs.isEmpty ) 
    throw new NoSuchElementException() 
  else 
    _max( xs, Int.MinValue );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With tail-recursion

```
  @tailrec
  def findMax(x: List[Int]):Int =  x match {
    case a :: Nil => a
    case a :: b :: c =>  findMax( (if (a > b) a else b) ::c)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With pattern matching to find max and return zero in case empty

```
  def findMax(list: List[Int]) = {
    def max(list: List[Int], n: Int) : Int = list match {
      case h :: t => max(t, if(h > n) h else n)
      case _ => n
    }
    max(list,0)
  }
```

Comment: When answering a question this old (over 5 years), and with so many answers already (15), it's a good idea to point out how your answer differs from the others. In this case I don't see much difference between you answer and the other pattern-matching answers.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is for the progfun-example

This is the simplest recursive solution I could come up with

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) throw new NoSuchElementException("The list is empty")
    val tail = xs.tail
    if (!tail.isEmpty) maxOfTwo(xs.head, max(xs.tail))
    else xs.head
  }

  def maxOfTwo(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
    if (x >= y) x
    else y
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
    case Nil => throw new NoSuchElementException("empty list!")
    case x :: Nil => x
    case x :: tail => if (x > max(tail)) x else max(tail)
  }
```

Comment: Could please provide some background as to why this code answers the question?

Comment: try max(List(1,22,5,2345,4,5,6))